# Mapping through an observable and return values of nested observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

hope you can help me out.

I have a function called getEnergyFromPower which returns a string of values:

```
getEnergyFromPower(systemId: number, objectId?: string) {
    ...

    return this.httpClient.get(this.BASE_URL + this.AGGREGATE_URL, {
      headers: this.BEARER_OPTIONS.headers,
      responseType: 'text',
      params: params
    })
  }
```

And another one that was supposed to loop through the values of an Observable.
But when I subscribe and console.log it it returns instead an array of observables like so:

```
organizeEnergy(systemId: number = 49439) {
    return this.getSystemLayout(systemId).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.map(({object_id}) => this.getEnergyFromPower(49439, object_id))
      })
    )
  }


this.optService.organizeEnergy().subscribe(res => console.log(res))

// Returns: 
// [Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable, Observable]
```

I tested to see if the object_id was right and it returns the right values like so:

```
organizeEnergy(systemId: number = 49439) {
    return this.getSystemLayout(systemId).pipe(
      map(res => {
        return res.map(({object_id}) => object_id)
      })
    )
  }

this.optService.organizeEnergy().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
//RETURNS 
// (8) [83978300, 83978301, 83978302, 83978303, 83978304, 83978305, 83978306, 83978307]
```

I also tested it hard coded like so and it works:

```
  organizeEnergy(systemId: number = 49439) {
    return this.getEnergyFromPower(systemId, '83978300')
  }

this.optService.organizeEnergy().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
//RETURNS 
// 2021/07/13 08:55:00.000,38
```

So I'm guessing my problem is when I try to map the response in this line:

```
organizeEnergy(systemId: number = 49439) {
     ...
        return res.map(({object_id}) => this.getEnergyFromPower(49439, object_id))
     ...
  }
```

So I would like to loop through it and dynamically the results whenever I subscribe to it.

Maybe it's something I didn't yet grasp since it's been two weeks I started with Angular/Observables/HttpClient

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to use a combination of `switchMap` and `combineLatest`.

```
import { combineLatest } form 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

organizeEnergy(systemId: number = 49439) {
    return this.getSystemLayout(systemId).pipe(
      // change map to switchMap because we are going to switch to a new observable
      switchMap(res => {
        // combine all HTTP requests and return the results as an array
        return combineLatest(...res.map(({object_id}) => this.getEnergyFromPower(49439, object_id)));
      }),
    )
  }

// This should give you [2021/07/13 08:55:00.000,38, ...]
this.optService.organizeEnergy().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
```